# frontier_exploration installation can't locate explore_client and explore_server in its package

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I'm running ROS Kinetic on Raspberry Pi.

So it seems that [frontier_exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration) package was successfully built via `git clone https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration.git` and `catkin_make`.

I've also downloaded [global_map.launch](https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration/blob/hydro-devel/launch/global_map.launch) and created a launch folder within frontier_exploration folder since it was not generated after installation.

However, running `roslaunch frontier_exploration global_map.launch` returns the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [frontier_exploration/explore_client]: can't locate node [explore_client] in package [frontier_exploration] 
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [frontier_exploration/explore_server]: can't locate node [explore_server] in package [frontier_exploration]
```

I have tried with ROS Melodic and the same error is printed after attempting to run. What could be the problem?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320143/frontier_exploration-installation-can%27t-locate-explore_client-and-explore_server-in-its-package./) by [ZeroSan](https://answers.ros.org/users/38110/zerosan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the launch file is in exploration_server folder. Running `rosrun exploration_server exploration.launch` worked.

---

Originally posted by [ZeroSan](https://answers.ros.org/users/38110/zerosan/) with karma: 55 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0